# How to apply list of functions to lists/variables?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

I have a list of functions of variable length

```
(list proc1 proc2 ...)
```

I have a list of variables

```
(list 1 2 3 4 5 ...)
```

I want to apply these functions to the variable list.

How can I apply these functions to my list?

Edit:

If I had sin cos and tan and 0.1, 0.2 and 0.3, then I want 9 results from that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a comprehension to iterate over the procedures and the numbers, you'll end up with a list with `n^2` elements. For example:

```
(for*/list ((f (list sin cos tan))
            (x (list 0.1 0.2 0.3)))
  (f x))

=> '(0.09983341664682815
     0.19866933079506122
     0.29552020666133955
     0.9950041652780257
     0.9800665778412416
     0.955336489125606
     0.10033467208545055
     0.20271003550867248
     0.3093362496096232)
```

Comment: @User it's a completely different thing that you're asking, see my updated answer.

Comment: `for*/list: this function is not defined`

Comment: @User change the language, make sure that `#lang racket` appears at the beginning of the file and select the option "determine language from source"  from the menu that pops up when pressing `Ctrl + L`. You tagged the question as `racket`, and `for*/list` is a Racket syntactic form.

Comment: Is `for*/list` the only way to do this? I'm looking to learn different approaches.

Comment: You could nest two `map`s, one inside the other. It's uglier but more standard. This technique is explained in the "Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs" book, check section 2.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Following are some approaches apart from for*/list :

One can get a list of lists by having 2 separate for/list :

```
(for/list ((f (list sin cos tan)))
  (for/list ((x (list 0.1 0.2 0.3)))
    (f x)))
```

Output:

```
'((0.09983341664682815 0.19866933079506122 0.29552020666133955)
  (0.9950041652780258 0.9800665778412416 0.955336489125606)
  (0.10033467208545055 0.2027100355086725 0.30933624960962325))
```

If one wants to use simple 'for', one can add the answer to an existing list:

```
(define outlist '())
(for ((f (list sin cos tan)))
  (for ((x (list 0.1 0.2 0.3)))
    (set! outlist (cons (f x) outlist))))
outlist
```

Output:

```
'(0.30933624960962325
  0.2027100355086725
  0.10033467208545055
  0.955336489125606
  0.9800665778412416
  0.9950041652780258
  0.29552020666133955
  0.19866933079506122
  0.09983341664682815)
```

Following is another version of using 'for':

```
(define fl (list sin cos tan))
(define vl (list 0.1 0.2 0.3))

(for* ((x 3)(y 3))         ; all combinations of x and y from (0,1,2)
  (println ((list-ref fl x) (list-ref vl y))))
```

'Named let' can also be used instead of 'for':

```
(let loop ((fl (list sin cos tan)))
  (cond
    [(empty? fl) (println "End.")]
    [else 
     (for ((v (list 0.1 0.2 0.3)))
       (println ((first fl) v)))
     (loop (rest fl))]))
```

Both for loops can also be replaced by 'named let':

```
(let outer ((fl (list sin cos tan)))
  (cond
    [(empty? fl)
     (println "End.")]
    [else 
     (let inner ((vl (list 0.1 0.2 0.3)))
       (cond
         [(empty? vl)]
         [else
          (println ((first fl) (first vl)))
          (inner (rest vl))]))
     (outer (rest fl))]))
```

Two maps can also be combined to get all values:

```
(map (λ (x)
       (map x (list 0.1 0.2 0.3)))
     (list sin cos tan))
```

Output:

```
'((0.09983341664682815 0.19866933079506122 0.29552020666133955)
  (0.9950041652780258 0.9800665778412416 0.955336489125606)
  (0.10033467208545055 0.2027100355086725 0.30933624960962325))
```

HTH.